# Python from Coursera - For Loop with a little math

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The question reads:

> Write a Python program that initializes a global variable to 5. The
>   keydown event handler updates this global variable by doubling it,
>   while the keyup event handler updates it by decrementing it by 3.
>
> What is the value of the global variable after 12 separate key
>   presses, i.e., pressing and releasing one key at a time, and repeating
>   this 12 times in total?
>
> To test your code, the global variable's value should be 35 after 4
>   key presses.

Rather than actually using their Coursera module and recreating the keyup and keydown events, I tried a for loop.

Any suggestions on how to correct what I have?

```
a = 5
for a in range(13):
    val = (a*2)-3

print val
```

Comment: And how your code is related to the assignment?

Comment: I wrote a for loop that tries to take the starting value of 5 and apply simple math 12 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for a in range (13)` overwrites a each time with a value from 0-12 and val is then calculated based on that instead of the "global" variable. this is probably not what you want to do.

maybe something like his?

```
a = 5
for i in range(12):
    a = (a*2)-3

print a
```

Comment: also it should be range(12)

Comment: why isn't it 13? as in range(0,13)? If you want it to loop 12 times shouldn't it be 13, because python stops one short of the 13 value?

Comment: because python starts counting at 0, not at 1. so, range (12) produces 12 values from 0 to 11

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are using a to calculate val:

```
val = (a*2)-3
```

I think you mixed up the 2 variables, Try this :

```
val = 5
a = 0
for a in range(0,4): #this make do the loop just 4 times
    val = (val*2)-3

print val
```

Because in your code a get values from 0 to 12, and you don't have to use that values, the operation you need to do is allways with the variable val if you initialize it to 5. In my code a make the for loop to do itself 4 times, and make the operations with val. at the end of the code you get 35 in val